# Compiling PyQt5 and SIP

Tags: python, makefile, pip, pyqt, pyqt5

I have Python3.8. I need PyQt5. I tried using pip (v22.2), but after compiling, it fails, citing make install returned Code 2. How do I force it to be more verbose and tell me what's the exact problem (I'm already running pip with -vvv).

Since it doesn't give any more details, I've no idea what causes it. Then I went on to compile it from source. PyQt 5.15.7 requires >= SIPv5.0.0. I went on and compiled and installed SIP 6.6.2. However, the actual executable that PyQt install script requires (/bin/sip) does not get installed at all. There are others sip-build, sip-wheel, etc. But the one that the configure script requires ('sip') does not get installed.

Where is the sip executable that PyQt configure.py requires (I can forward it with --sip switch)?

I have no idea how to progress. I am on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Why can't you use the official ubuntu pyqt5 packages?

Comment: I don't think 18.04 has Python 3.8 > in the repos, which I need. Installing pyqt this way would install it for a lower version it provides (3.6). I might be wrong? I don't have much experience with apt and debian.

Comment: It's taking things a bit too literally to interpret "requires >= SIPv5.0.0" as saying that any version at all of SIP will do, as long as it's at least v5.0.0.  Yes, that is *technically* what it says, and perhaps that's why `pip` is having trouble too, but an increase in major version number usually conveys a break in backwards compatibility. That doesn't necessarily mean absence of any backwards compatibility at all, but it does suggest that it might be worth your while to try SIP 5.5.0 or even SIP 5.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use 'python3 configure.py build' to build PyQt5, instead, since you are using sip => 6, then run the following command from the PyQt5 source root:
(sip 6 will make sip-build and sip-install executables in your python bin dir)

```
sip-install
```

This command, will compile and install PyQt5 (sip-build will only build it)